# Get argument value from function call

Tags: r, neural-network

How do I get (potentially un-filled) value of argument in function call? I am trying to get an information if `linout` is true or false for fitted `nnet` model.

Example:

```
library(nnet)
df <- data.frame(a = runif(10), b = runif(10), c = runif(10) > .5)
fit <- nnet(c ~ ., data = df, size = 3)
fit$call
> nnet.formula(formula = c ~ ., data = df, size = 3)
```

Here I know that `linout` is `FALSE` as this is the default value. But there also may be something like:

```
nnet.formula(formula = c ~ ., data = df, size = 3, lin = T)
```

Here, I would need to do some partial matching from `lin` to `linout` and get `T`

Comment: if lin = TRUE was given, then it would show up in $call. what about `formals(nnet.default)$linout`

Comment: @rawr: I think that would only examine the function definition, not the call that was made to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two nnet-methods. You are using the formula method and supplying an argument for linout using partial matching. This would test whether any of the argument names started with "lin":

```
fit <- nnet(c ~ ., data = df, size = 3, lin=TRUE)
# weights:  13
# snipped output
fit$call
nnet.formula(formula = c ~ ., data = df, size = 3, lin = TRUE)
as.logical( max( unlist( lapply(names(fit$call), grep, patt="lin"))) )
#[1] TRUE
```

It's interesting to see how `lapply` handles call-objects:

```
> fit$call
nnet.formula(formula = c ~ ., data = df, size = 3, lin = FALSE)
> lapply(fit$call, class)
[[1]]
[1] "name"

$formula
[1] "call"

$data
[1] "name"

$size
[1] "numeric"

$lin
[1] "logical"
```